# Modifying json in azure data factory to give nested list

Tags: azure-data-factory

Im retrieving data from sql server in Azure Data Factory.
The API im passing it to requires the Json in a specific format.

I have been unable to get the data in the required format so far, trying "for json output" in tsql.

is there a way to do this in data factory with the data it retrieved from SQL Server?

SQL Server Output

```
EntityName      customField1 CustomField2
------------------------------------------
AA01            NGO21        2022-01-01
AA02            BS34         2022-03-01
```

How it appears in Data Factory

```
[
{"EntityName": "AA01", "CustomField1": "NGO21", "CustomField2":"2022-01-01"},
{"EntityName": "AA02", "CustomField1": "BS32", "CustomField2":"2022-03-01"}
]
```

Required output

```
[
    {
        "EntityName": "AA01"
        "OtherFields":[{"customFieldName": "custom field 1, "customFieldValue": "NGO21"},{"customFieldName": "custom field 2", "customFieldValue": "2022-01-01"} ]
    },
    {
        "EntityName": "AA02"
        "OtherFields":[{"customFieldName": "CustomField1", "customFieldValue": "BS34"},{ "CustomFieldName":"CustomField2", "customFieldValue" : "2022-03-01"}]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it in ADF, the solution is quite long, i think if you will write a stored procedure, it will be much easier.

Here is a quick demo that i built:

the idea is to build the Json structure as requested and then using collect function to build the array.

we have 2 arrays, one for **EntityName** and one for **OtherFields**.

**Prepare the data**:

First, i added column names in the corresponding rows, we will use this info later on to build our Json, i used a Derived column activity to fill the rows with column names.

[image]

**Splitting Columns:**
In order to build the Json structure as requested, i split the data into two parallel flows.

first flow is to select CustomFieldName1 and CustomFieldValue1 and the second flow is to select CustomFieldName2 and CustomFieldValue2 like so:

**SelectColumn2 Activity:**

[image]

**SelectColumn1 Activity:**

[image]

**Note**: Please keep the **EntityName**, We will Union the data by it later on in the flow.

**OtherFields Column:**

In order to build the Json, we need to do it using Sub-columns feature in a Derived column activity, that will ensure to us the Json structure.

Add new column with a name 'OtherFields' and open Expression Builder:
add 2 subcolumns : CustomFieldName and CustomFieldValue, add CustomFieldName1 as a value for the subcolumn CustomFieldName and add CustomFieldValue1 to the CustomFiedValue column like so:

[image]

[image]

**Add a derived column activity and repeat same steps to CustomFieldName2.**

**Union:**

Now we have 2 flows, one for extracting field1 and field2, we need to Union the data (you can do it by position or by name)

[image]

In order to create an array of Json we need to aggregate the data; this will transform complex data type `{}` into array `[]`

**Aggregate Activity:**

Group by -> '**EntityName**'
Aggregates -> **collect**(OtherFields)

[image]

**Building Outer Json:**

as described in the question above , we need to have a json that consists of 2 columns : `{"EntitiyName" :"" , "OtherFields":[]}`

In order to do it, again we need to add a derived column and add 2 subcolumns,

also, in order to combine all Json's in one Json array, we need a common value so we can aggregate by it, since we have different values, i added a dummy value with a constant 1, this will guarantee to us that all Json's will be under the same array

[image]

**Aggregate Data Json Activity: **

the output is an array of Json's, so we need to aggregate the data column

Group by -> dummy
aggregate :  collect(data)

[image]

**SelectDataColumn Activity:**

Select Data column because we want it to be our output.
[image]

Finally, write to sink.

P.s: you can extract data value so you wont end up with a data key.

**Output:**

[image]

**ADF activities:**

[image]

You can read more about it here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-column-pattern

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-union

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-derived-column